# Parent gitignore to ignore any subdirectory gitignore files

Tags: git, gitignore

Is there a way through a `.gitignore` file (or some way through git version control) to ignore the effects of `.gitignore` files in subdirectories? The particular use case is that I'm copying open source folders into my git repo, and those open source folders have their own `.gitignore` files that I would like to ignore. I don't want to go through the process of manually deleting them because any time I bring the latest source folder over I'd have to remember/automate/etc. removing those files. Rather, I'd like to be able to have a folder structure like below:

```
file1.c
.gitignore
module1/
  src1.c
  .gitignore
  ...
module2/
  src2.c
  .gitignore
  ...
```

Where the root `.gitignore` is applied, but all `.gitignore`'s in the module folders are ignored. It's not a problem if they're committed to source control. But the goal is to ignore the impacts of the contents of those `.gitignore` files in the overall directory.

Comment: Short answer: no way. Probably `module1`, `module2`, etc should be submodules (separate repositories), not subdirectories?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this through `.gitignore` files, because they have a hierarchy / priority system where the "inner" `.gitignore` overrides any instructions from the "outer" `.gitignore`.  Hence even if you add outer `.gitignore` negations:

```
!inner/foo
```

to try to stop `inner/.gitignore` from listing `inner/foo`, it doesn't do it.

You *can*, however, do this through `.git/info/excludes`, as it has higher priority than *any* `.gitignore`.  The `.git/info/excludes` file is never *committed* so you'll have to store the data elsewhere (e.g., in a file that is committed) and then copy it into place in each clone you make.

I don't know your real ultimate goal, but this smells like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).